# how to find multiple non-repeating numbers in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a below method that finds the non-repeating elements in a list:

```
def dupes(a):
    s = {}
    for ele in a:
        if ele not in s:
            s[ele] = 1
        else:
            s[ele] += 1
    for x in s:
        if s[x] == 1:
            return 'this is the only non-repeating element value is :', s[x], 'and the key is :', x
    return

l = [4, 7, 4, 5, 7, 6, 5, 6, 10]
cd = dupes(l)
print("This is dupes: ", cd)
```

The code runs successfully and below is the output:

```
This is dupes:  ('this is the only non-repeating element value is :', 1, 'and the key is :', 10)
```

But when I am trying to add more than one non-repeating elements in the list, the output doesn't change. For example, if I add 11 at the end of the list the output still remains the same as above..

Any idea?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  What do you get with your data and flow tracing?  This is basic debugging that we expect  you to supply with your question.

Comment: added the program's output now

Comment: You are returning from the function when you find the first element.  It doesn't look for any more.

Comment: return will exit the loop and the function. Try to capture all the values first and then send the final result using the return statement

Comment: The reason why it only shows one value, is because you return (aka terminate) the function if you find one element. Adding the unique elements to a list and then returning that list, is a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when you return at the 10th line, the function ends. This is in case you don't understand the list comprehension yet, as many have given you the solution with that technique. I will just give you a simple solution where it will return a list of non-repeating numbers.

```
def dupes(a):
    s = {}
    non_dupes = []
    for ele in a:
        if ele not in s:
            s[ele] = 1
        else:
            s[ele] += 1
    for x in s:
        if s[x] == 1:
            non_dupes.append(x)
    return non_dupes

l = [4, 7, 4, 5, 7, 6, 5, 6, 10, 11]
cd = dupes(l)
print("This is dupes: ", cd)
```

Comment: @user3521180 Could you share why picked this answer over others?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all keys whose value is 1 using a list comprehension.

```
nondupes = [k for (k,v) in s.items() if v==1]
return 'Non-repeating elements: ' + str(nondupes)
```

Also, you could replace all your counting code with a `collections.Counter`:

```
s = Counter(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def dupes(a):
    s = {}
    for ele in a:
        if ele not in s:
            s[ele] = 1
        else:
            s[ele] += 1
    count = 0
    keys = []
    for x in s:
        if s[x] == 1:
            count += 1
            keys.append(x)
    return 'this is the only non-repeating element value is :', count, 'and the key is :', keys
```

That would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can succinctly achieve the above with [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
l = [4, 7, 4, 5, 7, 6, 5, 6, 10]
c = Counter(l)
dupes = list(key for key in c if c[key] > 1)
print("This is dupes: ", dupes)
```

Output:

```
This is dupes:  [4, 7, 5, 6]
```

The issue that you are encountering is that you are returning prematurely from your function with a string containing the first duplicate.  The rest of the duplicates are lost.

You already have the list of duplicates, let's `return` just the data so we can separate the calculation of results from the display of results.

```
return list(e for e in s if s[e] > 1)
```

Comment: There won't be duplicates anyway, so you don't need set

Comment: @RufusVS I was inferring from the code that was written what might be appropriate material to learn about.  Considering the topic is duplicates, I would say it is relevant.

Comment: @RufusVS I'm inclined to agree, I removed `set` from answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can easely solve this in one line of python code, using the `count()` function:

```
l = [4, 7, 4, 5, 7, 6, 5, 6, 10 ,11]

only_one_time = [e for e in l if l.count(e) < 2]

print(only_one_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

The given code returns the **first** non-repeating element it encounters.
For example,
if the input list is `l = [12, 11, 4, 7, 4, 5, 7, 6, 5, 6, 10]`,
the output would be `This is dupes:  ('this is the only non-repeating element value is :', 1, 'and the key is :', 12)`.

Comment: good answer, try to provide code that will fix the problem

Comment: I guess, I have what I was looking for, Thank you all.